# Как запустить активности через строковую переменную

Tags: java, android

Хочу запускать акутивности из массива строк типа такого

```
ListView lv;
String st[] = { "MyActivity1.class", "MyActivity2.class" };
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, st[i].getClass());
    startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

но никак не получается...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вызываете метод `getClass()` для элементов строкового массива, то есть, для строк. Значит, вы всегда получаете класс `String`.

Для получения класса по имени в Java можно воспользоваться, например, методом `forName()` класса `Class`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class.forName(st[i]));
```

Только имя класса, передаваемого в метод `forName()`, если я не ошибаюсь, должно быть полным, начиная от вершины иерархии пакетов приложения. Например:

```
org.pack1.pack2.pack3.MyActivity
```

И расширение `.class` писать не нужно.

Comment: я так пробовал, но у меня не срабатывало потому что я делал "MyActivity1", а не "com.example.myapplication.MyActivity1"